# Flipping a bitmap but keeping original file size

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, filesize

I have something that requires the the same filesize after modifying the BMP file, but when I try to flip it, the filesize of the resulting file changes.

```
Bitmap pic = new Bitmap(input);
pic.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipX);
pic.Save("test.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by same file size.

Comment: @Mitch: Say the original bmp size was 2436kb. The new, saved bmp's file should also be 2436kb.

Comment: Probably depends on what created the original image.  If you open your saved flipped picture, and flip it again and save it, is it the same size?

Comment: @Baddack: In Photoshop, yes.

Comment: Most parsers will not roundtrip an arbitrary file with the exact same size.  Why is this a requirement? Is there any tolerance?

Comment: @Mitch: I'm modifying a file of a format that is not known publicly and is without documentation. I have no clue at all on what to change to modify the filesize, but I guess that's what has to be done. With permission, of course.

Comment: Not photoshop, this code of course. Flip twice and compare to original.

Comment: I just ran your snippet with a .bmp and the output file was the same size as the input file. Presumably the format that you're using has a different encoding than .bmp. Do you have access to the raw pixel data and an encoder for the format? If a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` is able to be constructed from your source image, you may be able to just save it using `pic.Save("test.<extension>", pic.RawFormat);`.

Comment: @PatrickPurcell: I'm sure the file is a bitmap file since the header is "BM6" (42 4D 36). If I save it with RawFormat, it outputs a PNG. About the raw pixel data and encoder, I'm not sure.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek: That kind of defeats the purpose, doesn't it? Anyways, yes, if I re-flip the output it's the same size as the first output file.

Comment: Well, that is understandable.  Hopefully that means you can rely upon details of the encoder, then.  If so, you should be able to identify the offset, stride, and format of the pixel data and work with it directly.  Using a general purpose bitmap decoder or encoder isn't something I would expect to work.

Comment: Here's an example bmp (archived): [Google Drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B90DdkMxMOEobGdXcjNfX2FraTg/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Well, one thing notable about that file is that it is in 16 bpp.

Comment: Now I see You compared reflipped file to "first output file", not original as You were asked. In that case my yesterday conclusion was not correct and I deleted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that the original is 16bpp and output is 32bpp. Bitmap is automatically converted to 32bpp, so You just have to convert it back (or use some library, that does not do this conversion automatically on file read):

```
    Bitmap pic = new Bitmap("example.bmp");

    Bitmap pic2 = new Bitmap(pic.Width, pic.Height, PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb555);

    for (int x = 0; x < pic.Width; ++x)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < pic.Height; ++y)
        {
            pic2.SetPixel(x, y, pic.GetPixel(x, y));
        }
    }

    pic2.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipX);
    pic2.Save("test.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

The best way to say what happens is to look into the file with hex viewer, bmp format is well documented: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

Comment: Ah, that did it! Thanks! I should really read up on bpp. Seems like a very annoying concept when dealing with some types of automation.